# Pre increment operator in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set state of variable as `setoffsetCount(++offsetCount)` or `setoffsetCount(--ofsetCount)` but I am not able to use this rather `setoffsetCount(ofsetCount+1)` `setofsetCount(offsetCount-1)`
is working fine.
How to use pre increment operator in React for setting the state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to do:

```
setofsetCount(ofsetCount+1)
```

because you are setting the new value to be the current one, plus one.

However, if you do:

```
setofsetCount(++ofsetCount)
```

you are mutating the state directly by first incrementing it by one and then setting the state with the updated value.

---

**TL:DR**

Continue doing `setofsetCount(ofsetCount+1)` because that's the correct way. The other approach you tried is anti-pattern.

<sup>Note, you have a spelling error. It's "offset", not "ofset" :)</sup>

Comment: But if in case I need pre-increment so Is there any way exist?

Comment: @RuhanikaTiwari, can you explain what you need that for?

Comment: I am implementing pagination where offset is passed for incrementing and decrementing values in UI so the value of offset is passed like
for all next operation offset+1 and for decrement operation offset-1.
so incrementing three time,offset values is getting passed as 0,1,2,3
and for decrementing it is taking as 4,3,2,1 (It should be 2,1)
again incrementing value is going as 0,1,2,3,4(It should be 2,3,4)
because it is running as post increment and post decrement..I want it as a pre increment and pre decrement operation

Comment: Can you not just, inside the render method where you are using the `offsetCount` variable use `{offsetCount + 1}`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` instead of `const` when you declare the state variable and it will work.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is saying "allow me to change the value of offsetCount", which may not be what OP actually wanted.